# Retrieving accessors in IronRuby

Tags: ironruby

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the value stored in the Person class.  The problem is just that after I define an instance of the Person class, I don't know how to retrieve it within the IronRuby code because the instance name is in the .NET part.

```
 /*class Person
        attr_accessor :name

                def initialize(strname)
                    self.name=strname
                end
    end*/

    //We start the DLR, in this case starting the Ruby version


 ScriptEngine engine = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();
        ScriptScope scope = engine.ExecuteFile("c:\\Users\\ron\\RubymineProjects\\untitled\\person.rb");

    //We get the class type
    object person = engine.Runtime.Globals.GetVariable("Person");

    //We create an instance
    object marcy = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(person, "marcy");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT: Just installed VS and IronRuby and tested everything.]

The easiest way I can think of would be to type `marcy` as `dynamic` instead of `object`, and just call the accessor (which if I remember correctly is actually represented as a property on the .NET side):

```
dynamic marcy = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(person, "marcy");
var name = marcy.name;
```

If you are not using .NET 4, you will have to go through the "ugly" string-based API:

```
var name = engine.Operations.InvokeMember(marcy, "name");
```

BTW: If you *do* use .NET 4, you can also simplify some of your other code. For example, `Globals` implements `IDynamicObject` and provides an implemention of `TryGetProperty` that emulates Ruby's `method_missing`, so all in all you could do something like this:

```
var engine = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();
engine.ExecuteFile("person.rb");
dynamic globals = engine.Runtime.Globals;
dynamic person = globals.Person;
dynamic marcy = person.@new("marcy"); // why does new have to be a reserved word?
var name = marcy.name;
```

Notice how you can just "dot into" `Globals` to get the `Person` global constant, instead of having to pass it in as a string and you can just call the `new` method on the `Person` class (although you unfortunately have to escape it because `new` is a reserved word, although it would be trivial for the parser to know the difference) to create an instance.